# export filtered data from a table to csv file

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to export data marked in a checkbox from a table to a csv file. The php code does the job. Data marked is exported to csv file,  but the column headings are not created and data is duplicated in each field.

```
<?php

require 'includes/conexion.php';

if( !isset($_POST['casilla']) OR !is_array($_POST['casilla']) ) {
    exit('No se ha seleccionado ningun dato para la exportacion');
}

$delimiter = ",";
$filename = "equipos" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

//create a file pointer
$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

//creaa los encabezados de las columnas
$fields = array('hostName', 'nSerie', 'modelo','cargador', 
                'maletin', 'docking','ratonTeclado', 'notas', 
                'user_id');
fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter); 
    
//extrae cada fila de datos, les da formato csv y los escribe en fichero creado
foreach ($_POST['casilla'] as $value) {

    $value="Select * from informatica where id = $value LIMIT 1"; 
    $result = $mysqli->query($value);

    while($d = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lineData = array($d['hostName'], $d['nSerie'], $d['modelo'], 
                          $d['cargador'], $d['maletin'], $d['docking'], 
                         $d['ratonTeclado'], $d['notas'], $d['user_id']);
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }
}   
//vuelve al principio de cada fila
fseek($f, 0);
 
//crea las cabeceras para la exportacion para descarga del archivo con el nombre y fecha
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

       
//Escribe toda la informacion restante de un puntero a un archivo 
fpassthru($f);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: *export filtered data from a table to csv file* `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE ..`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string like `O'Neal'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blatantly borrowed from the PHP manual *go figure*

*If you need to send a CSV file directly to the browser, without writing in an external file, you can open the output and use fputcsv on it..*

```
<?php
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, array('this','is some', 'csv "stuff", you know.'));
fclose($out);
?>
```

So applying this generally available knowledge to your code, you could do

```
<?php
require 'includes/conexion.php';

if( !isset($_POST['casilla']) OR !is_array($_POST['casilla']) ) {
    exit('No se ha seleccionado ningun dato para la exportacion');
}

$delimiter = ",";
$filename = "equipos" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

//create a file pointer
$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

//creaa los encabezados de las columnas
$fields = array('hostName', 'nSerie', 'modelo','cargador', 
                'maletin', 'docking','ratonTeclado', 'notas', 
                'user_id');
fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter); 


// prepare a query, only once, but you can still amend the parameter 
// as many times as you like in the BIND, reusing the prepared query
$sql = 'Select * from informatica where id = ? LIMIT 1'; 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    
//extrae cada fila de datos, les da formato csv y los escribe en fichero creado
foreach ($_POST['casilla'] as $id) {

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // as you have a limit 1 on your query there is no need for a loop
    //while($d = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $d =  $result->fetch_assoc();
    
    $lineData = array($d['hostName'], $d['nSerie'], $d['modelo'], 
                      $d['cargador'], $d['maletin'], $d['docking'], 
                      $d['ratonTeclado'], $d['notas'], $d['user_id']);
    fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
}   
//vuelve al principio de cada fila
// not sure what this was for, but not needed now
//fseek($f, 0);
 
//crea las cabeceras para la exportacion para descarga del archivo con el nombre y fecha

fclose($f);
```

Comment: Yes, I have borrowed the code to see if it could work in what I am doing, but is not creating the column headings. I have also tried your suggestions and it does not work either. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This code is now tested and working. I made a couple of simple spelling errors in the original answer, sorry